# `req.connection.getPeerCertificate` returns nothing when the connection has a valid certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have inherited the following code on a NodeJS server:

```
/**
 * clientAuthMiddleware checks inbound requests and validates that the client
 * request is using a certificate signed by the CA
 * @param {*} params Takes the standard request, response, and next web 
 * paraameters as input.
 * @returns {*} If the certificate check passes it sends the request to the next
 * handler in the chain otherwise it returns a 401 error.
 */
const clientAuthMiddleware = () => (req, res, next) => {
  debugger; // TODO - need to remove this
  const cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate();
  if (cert.subject) {
    req.user = {
      subject: cert.subject.CN,
      issuer: cert.issuer.CN,
      organizational_unit: cert.subject.OU,
      organization: cert.subject.O,
      country: cert.subject.C,
    };
    return next();
  } else {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .send({error: `Sorry, but you need to provide a client certificate to continue.`});
  }
};
```

When I send the command:

```
curl 'http://10.10.25.130:3000/api/auth'   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -H 'Accept-Language: zh-TW,zh'   -H 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'   -H 'Connection: keep-alive'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Referer: http://10.10.25.130:3000/'   -H 'Sec-GPC: 1'   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'   --compressed   --insecure --cert ./grant.test.lan.crt.pem --key ./grant.test.lan.key.pem;
```

It returns: "Sorry, but you need to provide a client certificate to continue." When I debug it, this line `const cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate();` returns `cert={}`. When I check the value of `req` I see:

```
  client: {
    _tlsOptions: {
      secureContext: {
        context: {
        },
      },
      isServer: true,
      server: {
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        requestTimeout: 300000,
        headersTimeout: 60000,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        connectionsCheckingInterval: 30000,
        joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
        _contexts: [
        ],
        requestCert: true,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        ALPNProtocols: new Uint8Array([8, 104, 116, 116, 112, 47, 49, 46, 49]),
        pfx: undefined,
        key: new Uint8Array([45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 66, 69, 71, 73, 78, 32, 80, 82, 73, 86, 65, 84, 69, 32, 75, 69, 89, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10, 77, 73, 73, 69, 118, 65, 73, 66, 65, 68, 65, 78, 66, 103, 107, 113, 104, 107, 105, 71, 57, 119, 48, 66, 65, 81, 69, 70, 65, 65, 83, 67, 66, 75, 89, 119, 103, 103, 83, 105, 65, 103, 69, 65, 65, 111, 73, 66, 65, 81, 67, 103, 71, 88, 87, 55, 43, 89, 77, 102, 105, 109, 54, 73, 10, 78, 84, 57, 65, 112, 114, 99, 108, 76, 67, 50, 113, 78, 84, 97, 100, 75, 110, 47, 110, 106, 73, 83, 67, 81, 121, 75, 117, 104, 82, 85, 112, 109, 88, 109, 87, 103, 110, 82, 78, 56, 111, 90, 54, 84, 48, 98, 54, 81, 99, 76, 110, 115, 78, 89, 121, 55, 82, 43, 110, 115, 101, 114, 77, 10, 89, 83, 85, 48, 90, 121, 113, 99, 97, 52, 75, 89, 74, 65, 115, 88, 105, 52, 54, 84, 75, 90, 54, 121, 84, 121, 115, 99, 120, 113, 76, 115, 49, 98, 89, 65, 101, 102, 118, 83, 105, 97, 102, 98, 101, 69, 56, 47, 73, 53, 107, 101, 51, 69, 54, 72, 120, 113, 117, 83, 84, 87, 88, 56, 10, 54, 57, 53, 110, 75, 68, 80, 114, 65, 78, 106, 78, 117, 65, 79, 50, 120, 74, 103, 119, 105, 106, 85, 109, 49, 90, 119, 113, 105, 88, 100, 98, 118, 109, 56, 90, 117, 97, 53, 47, 97, 53, 65, 72, 102, 101, 90, 53, 97, 76, 103, 118, 107, 114, 51, 86, 115, 67, 102, 109, 71, 77, 104, 114, 10, 85, 50, 77, 50, 97, 81, 54, 88, 118, 122, 98, 85, 81, 117, 89, 85, 56, 56, 105, 48, 67, 120, 73, 75, 56, 83, 54, 51, 105, 69, 113, 109, 81, 72, 66, 53, 103, 103, 50, 118, 83, 56, 66, 120, 66, 75, 72, 116, 57, 49, 51, 89, 113, 104, 105, 74, 112, 111, 106, 87, 83, 51, 50, 10, 119, 86, 49, 77, 101, 68, 108, 72, 120, 107, 43, 75, 99, 54, 55, 84, 73, 54, 82, 76, 65, 114, 53, 109, 76, 100, 55, 100, 80, 75, 84, 88, 112, 102, 80, 90, 57, 77, 73, 102, 85, 67, 104, 83, 103, 52, 76, 79, 79, 97, 54, 110, 49, 107, 75, 85, 55, 84, 52, 71, 78, 101, 75, 66, 10, 55, 99, 89, 101, 120, 81, 84, 102, 65, 103, 77, 66, 65, 65, 69, 67, 103, 103, 69, 65, 70, 54, 76, 97, 110, 109, 100, 101, 89, 43, 119, 119, 109, 70, 120, 103, 71, 55, 47, 104, 80, 120, 81, 119, 73, 55, 90, 97, 101, 48, 97, 89, 102, 111, 116, 103, 122, 115, 104, 120, 109, 78, 108, 100, 10, 47, 47, 102, 65, 71, 121, 102, 107, 87, 116, 79, 111, 53, 101, 114, 74, 88, 69, 52, 85, 73, 57, 101, 89, 77, 65, 109, 82, 67, 70, 86, 56, 105, 68, 76, 53, 90, 113, 121, 113, 102, 108, 66, 106, 66, 101, 111, 103, 86, 120, 103, 76, 56, 119, 56, 77, 100, 108, 43, 52, 121, 106, 86, 76, 10, 80, 88, 76, 112, 118, 86, 86, 70, 66, 57, 97, 53, 50, 79, 50, 65, 113, 90, 52, 115, 84, 52, 71, 80, 43, 72, 121, 115, 118, 78, 115, 47, 97, 79, 69, 55, 119, 118, 103, 77, 47, 105, 57, 119, 85, 113, 76, 78, 114, 90, 67, 70, 116, 88, 106, 97, 69, 119, 77, 114, 88, 74, 52, 87, 10, 72, 53, 115, 100, 102, 122, 113, 75, 120, 113, 80, 120, 118, 51, 57, 115, 82, 89, 54, 73, 102, 68, 121, 83, 86, 115, 47, 115, 107, 99, 50, 101, 51, 78, 112, 78, 104, 70, 55, 73, 71, 121, 88, 82, 120, 67, 43, 105, 43, 65, 104, 101, 122, 117, 51, 107, 53, 119, 112, 87, 121, 78, 111, 100, 10, 50, 100, 122, 80, 122, 105, 48, 112, 116, 79, 43, 106, 115, 102, 98, 122, 48, 70, 56, 116, 87, 85, 97, 71, 118, 107, 85, 65, 98, 111, 110, 84, 49, 117, 115, 53, 78, 65, 121, 119, 107, 70, 67, 110, 77, 120, 77, 48, 54, 73, 78, 69, 116, 104, 115, 102, 106, 76, 122, 86, 120, 70, 102, 73, 10, 56, 88, 53, 102, 52, 109, 52, 72, 118, 102, 103, 110, 78, 89, 79, 121, 51, 80, 43, 121, 68, 70, 83, 90, 74, 101, 56, 114, 122, 86, 54, 108, 69, 119, 114, 67, 83, 65, 122, 102, 81, 75, 66, 103, 81, 68, 72, 83, 54, 82, 51, 71, 99, 101, 105, 84, 87, 107, 78, 121, 78, 47, 114, 10, 83, 117, 74, 88, 48, 72, 73, 53, 48, 86, 103, 52, 57, 106, 83, 100, 85, 72, 119, 85, 73, 97, 97, 77, 108, 115, 80, 78, 113, 90, 79, 50, 65, 80, 71, 47, 90, 73, 109, 107, 74, 119, 47, 57, 57, 51, 101, 90, 1, 66, 80, 78, 84, 76, 48, 114, 99, 74, 47, 74, 103, 52, 10, 66, 81, 52, 97, 70, 68, 116, 67, 86, 89, 120, 100, 67, 65, 84, 114, 88, 97, 47, 101, 108, 74, 99, 54, 105, 120, 98, 71, 108, 73, 57, 47, 110, 90, 97, 118, 110, 85, 113, 66, 72, 98, 106, 78, 99, 87, 73, 65, 76, 65, 72, 57, 67, 110, 101, 55, 54, 71, 115, 56, 111, 76, 52, 77, 10, 86, 86, 56, 111, 122, 51, 51, 100, 120, 110, 49, 52, 113, 84, 80, 120, 57, 78, 105, 110, 97, 110, 89, 99, 82, 81, 75, 66, 103, 81, 68, 78, 112, 116, 102, 72, 112, 112, 55, 76, 113, 57, 105, 67, 79, 53, 57, 116, 53, 76, 108, 79, 52, 66, 87, 113, 97, 86, 81, 48, 115, 71, 109, 65, 10, 103, 52, 118, 110, 121, 68, 56, 49, 76, 117, 99, 108, 85, 54, 104, 122, 77, 118, 102, 47, 52, 105, 87, 98, 57, 77, 54, 72, 84, 102, 66, 81, 88, 87, 73, 49, 80, 121, 111, 114, 50, 57, 83, 50, 97, 89, 55, 118, 84, 105, 54, 65, 81, 76, 53, 74, 111, 84, 50, 70, 119, 115, 52, 97, 10, 54, 114, 68, 47, 85, 66, 47, 89, 76, 71, 50, 66, 50, 98, 66, 104, 65, 118, 118, 77, 84, 108, 52, 74, 117, 65, 121, 109, 76, 104, 74, 112, 68, 85, 112, 114, 69, 120, 53, 110, 89, 106, 74, 76, 83, 77, 71, 56, 106, 100, 66, 53, 118, 54, 70, 87, 101, 122, 105, 79, 121, 122, 52, 120, 10, 65, 112, 100, 56, 88, 67, 82, 89, 48, 119, 75, 66, 103, 68, 115, 78, 97, 57, 99, 113, 109, 86, 43, 55, 74, 107, 84, 67, 88, 54, 56, 100, 105, 107, 72, 81, 55, 118, 101, 52, 48, 122, 90, 86, 112, 98, 78, 122, 100, 77, 67, 87, 85, 47, 53, 87, 99, 103, 66, 80, 110, 103, 103, 81, 10, 56, 90, 68, 118, 110, 109, 85, 52, 101, 101, 71, 98, 52, 83, 70, 122, 116, 66, 88, 72, 83, 53, 112, 49, 102, 109, 48, 69, 72, 113, 113, 67, 118, 80, 72, 51, 83, 114, 80, 87, 71, 51, 103, 53, 100, 120, 79, 121, 116, 47, 106, 119, 43, 72, 113, 78, 87, 104, 116, 80, 83, 57, 72, 90, 10, 104, 82, 118, 87, 78, 73, 120, 98, 110, 84, 87, 113, 119, 103, 111, 104, 65, 66, 110, 86, 98, 122, 77, 76, 112, 68, 76, 98, 119, 108, 82, 118, 79, 51, 111, 104, 79, 84, 57, 115, 111, 67, 77, 80, 112, 43, 101, 113, 48, 69, 79, 84, 74, 82, 111, 116, 65, 111, 71, 65, 90, 118, 53, 109, 10, 70, 118, 70, 86, 109, 102, 57, 73, 103, 89, 68, 71, 121, 99, 122, 66, 71, 99, 87, 85, 86, 68, 74, 73, 72, 57, 77, 121, 73, 49, 67, 43, 89, 113, 105, 104, 76, 48, 116, 56, 75, 43, 43, 72, 55, 53, 110, 90, 74, 109, 102, 109, 71, 103, 77, 121, 53, 65, 83, 101, 108, 69, 69, 81, 10, 106, 69, 90, 69, 73, 111, 56, 73, 75, 119, 115, 87, 115, 76, 98, 104, 66, 119, 53, 118, 111, 53, 111, 78, 51, 78, 109, 115, 89, 104, 85, 101, 75, 108, 121, 75, 86, 117, 109, 120, 70, 57, 51, 118, 68, 52, 52, 83, 81, 118, 43, 103, 76, 79, 83, 99, 105, 43, 107, 118, 77, 81, 82, 10, 80, 121, 114, 109, 69, 84, 84, 87, 112, 50, 109, 97, 122, 89, 110, 103, 110, 80, 106, 105, 72, 109, 79, 55, 52, 90, 102, 99, 88, 56, 78, 67, 104, 116, 47, 71, 118, 69, 48, 67, 103, 89, 65, 47, 53, 102, 68, 114, 111, 90, 70, 73, 78, 66, 65, 57, 43, 102, 72, 104, 53, 120, 122, 75, 10, 113, 107, 86, 82, 111, 70, 86, 55, 120, 49, 49, 121, 103, 77, 121, 112, 118, 76, 110, 79, 109, 78, 66, 102, 99, 76, 99, 69, 120, 88, 69, 69, 54, 122, 55, 74, 80, 111, 84, 65, 117, 112, 100, 109, 122, 103, 110, 47, 80, 111, 110, 55, 105, 47, 122, 65, 111, 111, 65, 70, 71, 122, 116, 118, 10, 111, 71, 73, 50, 100, 98, 75, 50, 88, 73, 84, 100, 112, 107, 102, 110, 112, 104, 99, 88, 98, 70, 99, 56, 50, 117, 71, 71, 48, 102, 75, 52, 56, 117, 112, 120, 105, 53, 122, 71, 47, 56, 66, 113, 75, 122, 83, 118, 85, 99, 57, 54, 50, 71, 47, 85, 49, 104, 107, 122, 51, 79, 75, 50, 10, 109, 57, 67, 85, 79, 89, 105, 50, 103, 69, 53, 116, 115, 83, 98, 99, 53, 112, 122, 83, 122, 81, 61, 61, 10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 69, 78, 68, 32, 80, 82, 73, 86, 65, 84, 69, 32, 75, 69, 89, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10]),
        passphrase: undefined,
        cert: new Uint8Array([45, 45, 45, 45, 66, 69, 71, 73, 78, 32, 67, 69, 82, 84, 73, 70, 73, 67, 65, 84, 69, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10, 77, 73, 73, 68, 114, 106, 67, 67, 65, 112, 97, 103, 65, 119, 73, 66, 65, 103, 73, 85, 82, 66, 101, 111, 107, 86, 98, 97, 86, 104, 55, 55, 49, 109, 43, 108, 113, 113, 72, 103, 70, 69, 99, 103, 122, 87, 103, 119, 68, 81, 89, 74, 75, 111, 90, 73, 104, 118, 99, 78, 65, 81, 69, 76, 10, 66, 81, 65, 119, 81, 68, 69, 82, 77, 65, 56, 71, 65, 49, 85, 69, 65, 119, 119, 73, 90, 71, 86, 115, 98, 67, 53, 106, 98, 50, 48, 120, 67, 122, 65, 74, 66, 103, 78, 86, 66, 65, 89, 84, 65, 108, 86, 84, 77, 81, 48, 119, 67, 119, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 73, 68, 65, 82, 80, 10, 97, 71, 108, 118, 77, 81, 56, 119, 68, 81, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 72, 68, 65, 90, 69, 89, 88, 108, 48, 98, 50, 52, 119, 72, 104, 99, 78, 77, 106, 77, 119, 78, 68, 73, 50, 77, 84, 89, 120, 77, 122, 77, 51, 87, 104, 99, 78, 77, 106, 81, 119, 78, 68, 73, 49, 77, 84, 89, 120, 10, 77, 122, 77, 51, 87, 106, 66, 112, 77, 81, 115, 119, 67, 81, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 71, 69, 119, 74, 86, 85, 122, 69, 78, 77, 65, 115, 71, 65, 49, 85, 69, 67, 65, 119, 69, 84, 50, 104, 112, 98, 122, 69, 80, 77, 65, 48, 71, 65, 49, 85, 69, 66, 119, 119, 71, 82, 71, 70, 53, 10, 100, 71, 57, 117, 77, 81, 48, 119, 67, 119, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 75, 68, 65, 82, 69, 90, 87, 120, 115, 77, 82, 65, 119, 68, 103, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 76, 68, 65, 100, 71, 90, 87, 82, 108, 99, 109, 70, 115, 77, 82, 107, 119, 70, 119, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 68, 68, 66, 66, 119, 10, 89, 88, 82, 106, 97, 71, 86, 122, 76, 109, 82, 108, 98, 71, 119, 117, 89, 50, 57, 116, 77, 73, 73, 66, 73, 106, 65, 78, 66, 103, 107, 113, 104, 107, 105, 71, 57, 119, 48, 66, 65, 81, 69, 70, 65, 65, 79, 67, 65, 81, 56, 65, 77, 73, 73, 66, 67, 103, 75, 67, 65, 81, 69, 65, 10, 111, 66, 108, 49, 117, 47, 109, 68, 72, 52, 112, 117, 105, 68, 85, 47, 81, 75, 97, 51, 74, 83, 119, 116, 113, 106, 85, 50, 110, 83, 112, 47, 53, 524, 111, 85, 86, 75, 90, 108, 53, 108, 111, 74, 48, 84, 102, 75, 71, 101, 107, 57, 71, 43, 107, 72, 67, 10, 53, 55, 68, 87, 77, 117, 48, 102, 112, 55, 72, 113, 122, 71, 69, 108, 78, 71, 99, 113, 110, 71, 117, 67, 109, 67, 81, 76, 70, 52, 117, 79, 107, 121, 109, 101, 115, 107, 56, 114, 72, 77, 97, 105, 55, 78, 87, 50, 65, 72, 110, , 48, 111, 109, 50, 51, 104, 80, 80, 121, 79, 90, 10, 72, 116, 120, 79, 104, 56, 97, 114, 107, 107, 49, 108, 47, 79, 118, 101, 90, 121, 103, 122, 54, 119, 68, 89, 122, 98, 103, 68, 116, 115, 83, 89, 77, 73, 111, 49, 74, 116, 87, 99, 75, 111, 108, 51, 87, 55, 53, 118, 71, 98, 109, 117, 102, 50, 117, 81, 66, 51, 51, 109, 101, 87, 105, 52, 10, 76, 53, 75, 57, 49, 98, 65, 110, 53, 104, 106, 73, 97, 49, 78, 106, 78, 109, 107, 79, 108, 55, 56, 50, 49, 69, 76, 109, 70, 80, 80, 73, 116, 65, 115, 83, 67, 118, 69, 117, 116, 52, 104, 75, 112, 107, 66, 119, 101, 89, 73, 78, 114, 48, 118, 65, 99, 81, 83, 104, 55, 102, 100, 100, 10, 50, 75, 116, 73, 89, 105, 97, 97, 73, 49, 107, 116, 57, 115, 70, 100, 84, 72, 103, 53, 82, 56, 90, 80, 105, 110, 79, 117, 48, 121, 79, 107, 83, 119, 75, 43, 90, 105, 51, 101, 51, 84, 121, 107, 49, 54, 88, 122, 50, 102, 84, 67, 72, 49, 65, 111, 85, 111, 79, 67, 122, 106, 109, 117, 10, 112, 57, 90, 67, 108, 79, 48, 43, 66, 106, 88, 105, 103, 101, 51, 71, 72, 115, 85, 69, 51, 119, 73, 68, 65, 81, 65, 66, 111, 51, 99, 119, 100, 84, 65, 102, 103, 78, 86, 72, 83, 77, 69, 71, 68, 65, 87, 103, 66, 81, 47, 105, 113, 74, 70, 77, 56, 97, 82, 52, 84, 119, 110, 10, 81, 119, 111, 74, 82, 117, 72, 80, 110, 115, 81, 117, 122, 106, 65, 74, 66, 103, 78, 86, 72, 82, 77, 69, 65, 106, 65, 65, 77, 65, 115, 71, 65, 49, 85, 100, 68, 119, 81, 69, 65, 119, 73, 69, 56, 68, 65, 98, 66, 103, 78, 86, 72, 82, 69, 69, 70, 68, 65, 83, 103, 104, 66, 119, 10, 89, 88, 82, 106, 97, 71, 86, 122, 76, 109, 82, 108, 98, 71, 119, 117, 89, 50, 57, 116, 77, 66, 48, 71, 65, 49, 85, 100, 68, 103, 81, 87, 66, 66, 81, 67, 67, 116, 100, 77, 104, 86, 48, 120, 47, 74, 118, 47, 47, 75, 101, 115, 54, 117, 57, 51, 90, 90, 55, 116, 119, 84, 65, 78, 10, 66, 103, 107, 113, 104, 107, 105, 71, 57, 119, 48, 66, 65, 81, 115, 70, 65, 65, 79, 67, 65, 81, 69, 65, 111, 118, 71, 77, 114, 74, 101, 114, 104, 48, 105, 102, 112, 50, 80, 77, 105, 122, 98, 100, 48, 86, 87, 102, 115, 77, 115, 114, 50, 82, 100, 72, 67, 121, 43, 50, 47, 84, 89, 85, 10, 86, 71, 110, 97, 87, 79, 66, 109, 47, 47, 66, 98, 47, 67, 114, 110, 70, 118, 98, 111, 83, 72, 98, 86, 108, 57, 117, 84, 115, 114, 110, 113, 113, 49, 76, 48, 50, 103, 50, 99, 78, 72, 50, 69, 76, 88, 78, 117, 83, 104, 118, 114, 111, 72, 76, 86, 68, 72, 111, 56, 75, 43, 82, 119, 10, 89, 120, 100, 115, 88, 99, 114, 121, 98, 73, 71, 83, 90, 47, 120, 52, 76, 47, 107, 74, 50, 43, 43, 86, 75, 106, 75, 65, 114, 101, 122, 101, 102, 75, 88, 68, 98, 70, 107, 69, 65, 67, 51, 89, 56, 53, 97, 106, 113, 118, 119, 118, 99, 52, 88, 117, 78, 90, 120, 104, 85, 84, 104, 68, 10, 89, 50, 101, 78, 71, 57, 105, 67, 104, 54, 50, 48, 87, 50, 51, 83, 71, 78, 122, 55, 52, 107, 111, 56, 114, 68, 112, 47, 122, 67, 65, 98, 78, 118, 108, 122, 116, 84, 74, 121, 66, 78, 76, 75, 89, 116, 69, 121, 56, 53, 83, 86, 108, 80, 66, 77, 97, 118, 121, 119, 76, 47, 105, 78, 10, 88, 67, 48, 115, 54, 73, 69, 107, 68, 114, 110, 111, 121, 116, 115, 56, 120, 53, 66, 77, 73, 108, 116, 79, 107, 110, 107, 86, 98, 68, 65, 109, 65, 73, 115, 71, 120, 83, 71, 49, 78, 114, 50, 85, 110, 118, 87, 104, 81, 56, 106, 120, 111, 50, 79, 76, 49, 118, 43, 56, 100, 109, 52, 112, 10, 100, 111, 65, 49, 88, 106, 88, 55, 110, 102, 119, 119, 88, 82, 109, 88, 100, 109, 109, 103, 87, 56, 80, 72, 121, 55, 74, 66, 103, 112, 47, 84, 56, 51, 74, 66, 71, 109, 76, 118, 111, 71, 97, 104, 110, 103, 61, 61, 10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 69, 78, 68, 32, 67, 69, 82, 84, 73, 70, 73, 67, 65, 84, 69, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10]),
        clientCertEngine: undefined,
        ca: undefined,
        minVersion: undefined,
        maxVersion: undefined,
        secureProtocol: undefined,
        crl: undefined,
        sigalgs: undefined,
        ciphers: undefined,
        ecdhCurve: undefined,
        dhparam: undefined,
        honorCipherOrder: true,
        secureOptions: undefined,
        sessionIdContext: "e41e7a050b458f074195bb3ce3f8b76b",
        privateKeyIdentifier: undefined,
        privateKeyEngine: undefined,
        _sharedCreds: {
          context: {
          },
        },
```

If I decode that with:

```
const certificate = new Uint8Array([45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 66, 69, 71, 73, 78, 32, 67, 69, 82, 84, 73, 70, 73, 67, 65, 84, 69, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10, 77, 73, 73, 68, 114, 106, 67, 67, 65, 112, 97, 103, 65, 119, 73, 66, 65, 103, 73, 85, 82, 66, 101, 111, 107, 86, 98, 97, 86, 104, 55, 55, 49, 109, 43, 108, 113, 113, 72, 103, 70, 69, 99, 103, 122, 87, 103, 119, 68, 81, 89, 74, 75, 111, 90, 73, 104, 118, 99, 78, 65, 81, 69, 76, 10, 66, 81, 65, 119, 81, 68, 69, 82, 77, 65, 56, 71, 65, 49, 85, 69, 65, 119, 119, 73, 90, 71, 86, 115, 98, 67, 53, 106, 98, 50, 48, 120, 67, 122, 65, 74, 66, 103, 78, 86, 66, 65, 89, 84, 65, 108, 86, 84, 77, 81, 48, 119, 67, 119, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 73, 68, 65, 82, 80, 10, 97, 71, 108, 118, 77, 81, 56, 119, 68, 81, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 72, 68, 65, 90, 69, 89, 88, 108, 48, 98, 50, 52, 119, 72, 104, 99, 78, 77, 106, 77, 119, 78, 68, 73, 50, 77, 84, 89, 120, 77, 122, 77, 51, 87, 104, 99, 78, 77, 106, 81, 119, 78, 68, 73, 49, 77, 84, 89, 120, 10, 77, 122, 77, 51, 87, 106, 66, 112, 77, 81, 115, 119, 67, 81, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 71, 69, 119, 74, 86, 85, 122, 69, 78, 77, 65, 115, 71, 65, 49, 85, 69, 67, 65, 119, 69, 84, 50, 104, 112, 98, 122, 69, 80, 77, 65, 48, 71, 65, 49, 85, 69, 66, 119, 119, 71, 82, 71, 70, 53, 10, 100, 71, 57, 117, 77, 81, 48, 119, 67, 119, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 75, 68, 65, 82, 69, 90, 87, 120, 115, 77, 82, 65, 119, 68, 103, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 76, 68, 65, 100, 71, 90, 87, 82, 108, 99, 109, 70, 115, 77, 82, 107, 119, 70, 119, 89, 68, 86, 81, 81, 68, 68, 66, 66, 119, 10, 89, 88, 82, 106, 97, 71, 86, 122, 76, 109, 82, 108, 98, 71, 119, 117, 89, 50, 57, 116, 77, 73, 73, 66, 73, 106, 65, 78, 66, 103, 107, 113, 104, 107, 105, 71, 57, 119, 48, 66, 65, 81, 69, 70, 65, 65, 79, 67, 65, 81, 56, 65, 77, 73, 73, 66, 67, 103, 75, 67, 65, 81, 69, 65, 10, 111, 66, 108, 49, 117, 47, 109, 68, 72, 52, 112, 117, 105, 68, 85, 47, 81, 75, 97, 51, 74, 83, 119, 116, 113, 106, 85, 50, 110, 83, 112, 47, 53, 52, 121, 69, 103, 107, 77, 105, 114, 111, 85, 86, 75, 90, 108, 53, 108, 111, 74, 48, 84, 102, 75, 71, 101, 107, 57, 71, 43, 107, 72, 67, 10, 53, 55, 68, 87, 77, 117, 48, 102, 112, 55, 72, 113, 122, 71, 69, 108, 78, 71, 99, 113, 110, 71, 117, 67, 109, 67, 81, 76, 70, 52, 117, 79, 107, 121, 109, 101, 115, 107, 56, 114, 72, 77, 97, 105, 55, 78, 87, 50, 65, 72, 110, 55, 48, 111, 109, 110, 50, 51, 104, 80, 80, 121, 79, 90, 10, 72, 118, 101, 90, 121, 103, 122, 54, 119, 68, 89, 122, 98, 103, 68, 116, 115, 83, 89, 77, 73, 111, 49, 74, 116, 87, 99, 75, 111, 108, 51, 87, 55, 53, 118, 71, 98, 109, 117, 102, 50, 117, 81, 66, 51, 51, 109, 101, 87, 105, 52, 10, 76, 53, 75, 57, 49, 98, 65, 110, 53, 104, 106, 73, 97, 49, 78, 106, 78, 109, 107, 79, 108, 55, 56, 50, 49, 69, 76, 109, 70, 80, 80, 73, 116, 65, 115, 83, 67, 118, 69, 117, 116, 52, 104, 75, 112, 107, 66, 119, 101, 89, 73, 78, 114, 48, 118, 65, 99, 81, 83, 104, 55, 102, 100, 100, 10, 50, 75, 116, 73, 89, 105, 97, 97, 73, 49, 107, 116, 57, 115, 70, 100, 84, 72, 103, 53, 82, 56, 90, 80, 105, 110, 79, 117, 48, 121, 79, 107, 83, 119, 75, 43, 90, 105, 51, 101, 51, 84, 121, 107, 49, 54, 88, 122, 50, 102, 84, 67, 72, 49, 65, 111, 85, 111, 79, 67, 122, 106, 109, 117, 10, 112, 57, 90, 67, 108, 79, 48, 43, 66, 106, 88, 105, 103, 101, 51, 71, 72, 115, 85, 69, 51, 119, 73, 68, 65, 81, 65, 66, 111, 51, 99, 119, 100, 84, 65, 102, 66, 103, 78, 86, 72, 83, 77, 69, 71, 68, 65, 87, 103, 66, 81, 47, 105, 113, 74, 70, 77, 56, 97, 82, 52, 84, 119, 110, 10, 81, 119, 111, 74, 82, 117, 72, 80, 110, 115, 81, 117, 122, 106, 65, 74, 66, 103, 78, 86, 72, 82, 77, 69, 65, 106, 65, 65, 77, 65, 115, 71, 65, 49, 85, 100, 68, 119, 81, 69, 65, 119, 73, 69, 56, 68, 65, 98, 66, 103, 78, 86, 72, 82, 69, 69, 70, 68, 65, 83, 103, 104, 66, 119, 10, 89, 88, 82, 106, 97, 71, 86, 122, 76, 109, 82, 108, 98, 71, 119, 117, 89, 50, 57, 116, 77, 66, 48, 71, 65, 49, 85, 100, 68, 103, 81, 87, 66, 66, 81, 67, 67, 116, 100, 77, 104, 86, 48, 120, 47, 74, 118, 47, 47, 75, 101, 115, 54, 117, 57, 51, 90, 90, 55, 116, 119, 84, 65, 78, 10, 66, 103, 107, 113, 104, 107, 105, 71, 57, 119, 48, 66, 65, 81, 115, 70, 65, 65, 79, 67, 65, 81, 69, 65, 111, 118, 71, 77, 114, 74, 101, 114, 104, 48, 105, 102, 112, 50, 80, 77, 105, 122, 98, 100, 48, 86, 87, 102, 115, 77, 115, 114, 50, 82, 100, 72, 67, 121, 43, 50, 47, 84, 89, 85, 10, 86, 71, 110, 97, 87, 79, 66, 109, 47, 47, 66, 98, 47, 67, 114, 110, 70, 118, 98, 111, 83, 72, 98, 86, 108, 57, 117, 84, 115, 114, 110, 113, 113, 49, 76, 48, 50, 103, 50, 99, 78, 72, 50, 69, 76, 88, 78, 117, 83, 104, 118, 114, 111, 72, 76, 86, 68, 72, 111, 56, 75, 43, 82, 119, 10, 89, 120, 100, 115, 88, 99, 114, 121, 98, 73, 71, 83, 90, 47, 120, 52, 76, 47, 107, 74, 50, 43, 43, 86, 75, 106, 75, 65, 114, 101, 122, 101, 102, 75, 88, 68, 98, 70, 107, 69, 65, 67, 51, 89, 56, 53, 97, 106, 113, 118, 119, 118, 99, 52, 88, 117, 78, 90, 120, 104, 85, 84, 104, 68, 10, 89, 50, 101, 78, 71, 57, 105, 67, 104, 54, 50, 48, 87, 50, 51, 83, 71, 78, 122, 55, 52, 107, 111, 56, 114, 68, 112, 47, 122, 67, 65, 98, 78, 118, 108, 122, 116, 84, 74, 121, 66, 78, 76, 75, 89, 116, 69, 121, 56, 53, 83, 86, 108, 80, 66, 77, 97, 118, 121, 119, 76, 47, 105, 78, 10, 88, 67, 48, 115, 54, 73, 69, 107, 68, 114, 110, 111, 121, 116, 115, 56, 120, 53, 66, 77, 73, 108, 116, 79, 107, 110, 107, 86, 98, 68, 65, 109, 65, 73, 115, 71, 120, 83, 71, 49, 78, 114, 50, 85, 110, 118, 87, 104, 81, 56, 106, 120, 111, 50, 79, 76, 49, 118, 43, 56, 100, 109, 52, 112, 10, 100, 111, 65, 49, 88, 106, 88, 55, 110, 102, 119, 119, 88, 82, 109, 88, 100, 109, 109, 103, 87, 56, 80, 72, 121, 55, 74, 66, 103, 112, 47, 84, 56, 51, 74, 66, 71, 109, 76, 118, 111, 71, 97, 104, 110, 103, 61, 61, 10, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 69, 78, 68, 32, 67, 69, 82, 84, 73, 70, 73, 67, 65, 84, 69, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 10]);
const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
const certificateString = decoder.decode(certificate);
console.log(certificateString);
```

I see:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrjCCApagAwIBAgIURBeokVbaVh771m+lqqHgFEcgzWgwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEL
BQAwQDERMA8GA1UEAwwIZGVsbC5jb20xCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQ0wCwYDVQQIDARP
aGlvMQ8wDQYDVQQHDAZEYXl0b24wHhcNMjMwNDI2MTYxMzM3WhcNMjQwNDI1MTYx
MzM3WjBpMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzENEPMA0GA1UEBwwGRGF5
dG9uMQ0wCwYDVQQKDAREZWxsMRAwDgYDVQQLDAdGZWRlcmFsMRkwFwYDVQQDDBBw
YXRjaGVzLmRlbGwuY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA
oBl1u/mDH4puiDU/QKa3JSwtqjU2nSp/54yEgkMiroUVKZl5loJ0TfKGek9G+kHC
57DWMu0fp7HqzGElNGcqnGuCmCQLF4uOkymesk8rHMai7NW2AHn70omn23hPPyOZ
HtxOh8arkk1l/OveZygz6wDYzbgDtsSYMIo1JtWcKol3W75vGbmuf2uQB33meWi4
L5K91bAn5SCvEut4hKpkBweYINr0vAcQSh7fdd
2KtIYiaaI1kt9sFdTHg5R8ZPinOu0yOkSwK+Zi3e3Tyk16Xz2fTCH1AoUoOCzjmu
p9ZClO0+BjXige3GHsUE3wIDAQABo3cwdTAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBQ/iqJFM8aR4Twn
QwoJRuHPnsQuzjAJBgNVHRMEAjAAMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIE8DAbBgNVHREEFDASghBw
YXRjaGVzLmRlbGwuY29tMB0GA1UdDgQWBBQCCtdMhV0x/Jv//Kes6u93ZZ7twTAN
BgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAovGMrJerh0ifp2PMizbd0VWfsMsr2RdHCy+2/TYU
VGnaWOBm//Bb/CrnFvboSHbVl9uTsrnShvroHLVDHo8K+Rw
YxdsXcrybIGSZ/x4L/kJ2++VKjKArezefKXDbFkEAC3Y85ajqvwvc4XuNZxhUThD
Y2eNG9iCh620W23SGNz74ko8rDp/zCAbNvlztTJyBNLKYtEy85SVlPBMavywL/iN
XC0s6IEkDrnoyts8x5BMIltOknkVbDAmAIsGxSG1Nr2UnvWhQ8jxo2OL1v+8dm4p
doA1XjX7nfwwXRmXdmmgW8PHy7JBgp/T83JBGmLvoGahng==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Finally, I run that through `openssl` like this:

```
[grant@patches server_certs]$ openssl x509 -in /tmp/test -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            44:17:a8:91:56:da:56:1e:fb:d6:6f:a5:aa:a1:e0:14:47:20:cd:68
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = test.lan, C = US, ST = Ohio, L = Dayton
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr 26 16:13:37 2023 GMT
            Not After : Apr 25 16:13:37 2024 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = Ohio, L = Dayton, O = Test, OU = Test, CN = test.grant.lan
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a0:19:75:bb:f9:83:1f:8a:6e:88:35:3f:40:a6:
                    b7:25:2c:2d:aa:35:36:9d:2a:7f:e7:8c:84:82:43:
                    22:ae:85:15:29:99:79:96:82:74:4d:f2:86:7a:4f:
                    46:fa:41:c2:e7:b0:d6:32:ed:1f:a7:b1:ea:cc:61:
                    25:34:67:2a:9c:6b:82:98:24:0b:17:8b:8e:93:29:
                    9e:b2:4f:2b:1c:c6:a2:ec:d5:b6:00:79:fb:d2:89:
                    a7:db:78:4f:3f:23:99:1e:dc:4e:87:c6:ab:92:4d:
                    65:fc:eb:de:67:28:33:eb:00:d8:cd:b8:03:b6:c4:
                    98:30:8a:35:26:d5:9c:2a:89:77:5b:be:6f:19:b9:
                    ae:7f:6b:90:07:7d:e6:79:68:b8:2f:92:bd:d5:b0:
                    27:e6:18:c8:6b:53:63:36:69:0e:97:bf:36:d4:42:
                    e6:14:f3:c8:b4:0b:12:0a:f1:2e:b7:88:4a:a6:40:
                    70:79:82:0d:af:4b:c0:71:04:a1:ed:f7:5d:d8:ab:
                    48:62:26:9a:23:59:2d:f6:c1:5d:4c:78:39:47:c6:
                    4f:8a:73:ae:d3:23:a4:4b:02:be:66:2d:de:dd:3c:
                    a4:d7:a5:f3:d9:f4:c2:1f:50:28:52:83:82:ce:39:
                    ae:a7:d6:42:94:ed:3e:06:35:e2:81:ed:c6:1e:c5:
                    04:df
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                3F:8A:A2:45:33:C6:91:E1:3C:27:43:0A:09:46:E1:CF:9E:C4:2E:CE
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:grant.test.lan
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                02:0A:D7:4C:85:5D:31:FC:9B:FF:FC:A7:AC:EA:EF:77:65:9E:ED:C1
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Signature Value:
        a2:f1:8c:ac:97:ab:87:48:9f:a7:63:cc:8b:36:dd:d1:55:9f:
        b0:cb:2b:d9:17:47:0b:2f:b6:fd:36:14:54:69:da:58:e0:66:
        ff:f0:5b:fc:2a:e7:16:f6:e8:48:76:d5:97:db:93:b2:b9:ea:
        ab:52:f4:da:0d:9c:34:7d:84:2d:73:6e:4a:1b:eb:a0:72:d5:
        0c:7a:3c:2b:e4:70:63:17:6c:5d:ca:f2:6c:81:92:67:fc:78:
        2f:f9:09:db:ef:95:2a:32:80:ad:ec:de:7c:a5:c3:6c:59:04:
        00:2d:d8:f3:96:a3:aa:fc:2f:73:85:ee:35:9c:61:51:38:43:
        63:67:8d:1b:d8:82:87:ad:b4:5b:6d:d2:18:dc:fb:e2:4a:3c:
        ac:3a:7f:cc:20:1b:36:f9:73:b5:32:72:04:d2:ca:62:d1:32:
        f3:94:95:94:f0:4c:6a:fc:b0:2f:f8:8d:5c:2d:2c:e8:81:24:
        0e:b9:e8:ca:db:3c:c7:90:4c:22:5b:4e:92:79:15:6c:30:26:
        00:8b:06:c5:21:b5:36:bd:94:9e:f5:a1:43:c8:f1:a3:63:8b:
        d6:ff:bc:76:6e:29:76:80:35:5e:35:fb:9d:fc:30:5d:19:97:
        76:69:a0:5b:c3:c7:cb:b2:41:82:9f:d3:f3:72:41:1a:62:ef:
        a0:66:a1:9e
```

and confirm that I get my valid test certificate back.

I'm lost as to why `getPeerCertificate` isn't returning the cert. Everything appears to be in working order.

Note: I tampered some of the values so I could post but at the end you do get a valid cert back.